# Viewing record based on record type

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I have one custom object related to Account. The custom object has 3 record types and I would like to control what record type opens for the user. Record Type (Master) opens an older force.com layout. Record type 2 opens a newer force.com object layout with 5 fields. Record type 3 should open a visual force page with many more fields.

What is the best way to allow a user to open a record that used any one of these record types/page layout assignments? Its a mix of force.com and visualforce so not sure what others have done in this case that I can leverage.

I am not trying to restrict access but merely allow the proper layout to be displayed based on the record type.

Updated Code:

I created a formula field on the customer Account Summary object to calculate the RecordTypeName__c rather than use the controller to figure that out.

The controller loads OK but when I add the jscript to the VisualForce page the page starts looping reloading itself and the VF page shows this error:

**'Attempt to de-reference a null object'**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload= function Redirect()
    {
        redirection();
    }
</script>
 <apex:actionFunction name="redirection" action="{!redirectAcctNewPage}" />

//Open and view page according to record type. There are multiple CRE versions with seperate record types. 
    public PageReference redirectAcctNewPage() {
    PageReference pageRef = null;    
    //Get RecordType  //used to redirect to correct pagetype when loaded.   
    this.RecordTypeName = this.AccountSummary.RecordTypeName__c;

    try {
        if(this.RecordTypeName.equals('New_Account_Summary'))
        {   
            pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/PROD_UW_AccountSummary');
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id', this.AccountSummary.Id);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);  
        }
        else 
        {
            pageRef = new PageReference('/' + this.AccountSummary.Id);
            pageRef.getParameters().put('inline', '0');
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);   
        }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
           return pageRef;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to access the record from List View of that Custom Object or from the related list of Account object.

Create a formula field with the same Name and use this code.

For example if recordtype is `Accounting` it will display standard page and for other recordtype it will open visualforce page.

```
   HYPERLINK(
   IF( RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Accounting', '/'+ Id , '/apex/yourVisualforcePage?id=' + Id
   ) 
    ,Name 
    , "_Parent" 
    )
```

**Update**

Override view action with Visualforce routing page like this (given an example taking Account object, logic is same, just you need to replace with your custom object):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" id="myPage" cache="true" showHeader="false" extensions="AccountController">
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="N"/>
    <apex:form id="myform">
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.onload= function Redirect()
            {
                redirection();
            }
        </script>
         <apex:actionFunction name="redirection" action="{!redirectAcctNewPage}" />
    </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Controller for routing

```
public Account acct {get; set;}   
public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)     
{   
    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') !=null)
    {
        acct = [Select id, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name from Account where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }        
}
 public PageReference redirectAcctNewPage() {

    if(acct.RecordType.Name.equals('Accounting'))
    {   
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController (new Account(Id=acct.Id))).view();
    }
    else 
    {
        pgrf = new PageReference('/apex/myVisualForcePage');
        pgrf.getParameters().put('id', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        pgrf.setRedirect(true);
        return  pgrf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62367/discussion-on-answer-by-santanu-boral-viewing-record-based-on-record-type).